# I cannot see other online members in Firebase real-time

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I won't be able to post all code here but the key areas only. I am trying to see members online but from the code I can only see myself(as attached screenshot). Before this I would as well want to use some sort of filter based on fields like gender, age group(one example will show me what to do) to show me who is online so I can proceed from there.
I am using real-time database for the location and online presence as well as Firestore for all other details.

Below is the code in question, my real-time database responds well to it from the console but only once, i.e. it shows online once and after going to the *listOnline class* and back to *MainActivity class*, the status remains offline.
The user to be displayed too I would like using their usernames NOT emails. Yes I tried that and somehow the whole thing had errors nearly everywhere

```
    private void displayLocation() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
    
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiCLient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                //Update Firebase
    
                locations.child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).
                        setValue(new Tracking(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                                String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),
                                String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()));
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Location Not Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
private void updateList() {
        mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(User.class,
                R.layout.user_layout, ListOnlineViewHolder.class, counterRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ListOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final User model, int position) {


                if (model.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getEmail())) {
                    System.out.println("Current user");
                    viewHolder.username.setText(String.valueOf(
                            model.getUserName()));
                    viewHolder.username.append("(Me)");
                }else {
                    viewHolder.username.setText(model.getUserName());
                }


                //implement update click listener


                viewHolder.itemClickListenener = new ItemClickListenener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                        //cant click current user logged in
                        //sending information of other users not one logged in
                        if (!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapTracking.class);
                            in.putExtra("email", model.getEmail());
                            in.putExtra("latitude", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                            in.putExtra("Longitude", mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                            startActivity(in);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        mFireAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listOnline.setAdapter(mFireAdapter);
    }
```

From a class called *tracking*, the code is as below

```
public class Tracking {
    private String mEmail,lat,lng,userName;

    public Tracking() {
    }

    public Tracking(String email, String uid, String lat, String lng,String userName) {
        this.mEmail = email;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
```

Am running with a real device, so below is the code from **run**

```
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7309a14000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7309a14000,bufferCount=3)
    Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7309a14000)
I/System.out: Current user
D/LOG:   is Online
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x730a9ca000,api=1)
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@6b16f27, this = DecorView@a027f28[MainActivity]
```

[screenshot with that message below displaying only me and not the others online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rchLx.png)

[real-time database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfBUF.jpg)
[firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lktP.jpg)

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo
No errors yes, but I cannot view other people online except me. Even when in my console they're online. Was wondering if I missed something from this code

Comment: How does your database look like?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have attached the two databases as screenshots now.